# Semantic-ui / Search - Custom HTTP_ACCEPT

Tags: coffeescript, semantic-ui, json-api

I'm doing a search module with Semantic-ui and I need to call a API in json:api format for my results. So i need to accept 'application/vnd.api+json' in the HTTP_ACCEPT header. 
Is there a way to overload the header with a callback before the ajax request is sent ?

```
  $('.ui.search')
    .search({
      type: 'recipe',
      apiSettings: {
        onRequest: (promise, xhr) ->
          xhr.setRequestHeader('HTTP_ACCEPT', 'application/vnd.api+json')
        url: '//staging-doeat.herokuapp.com/api/v1/recipes',
        onResponse: (response) ->
          console.log(response)
      },
  });
```

I would like to do something like this. But it doesn't work.

Thanks u for your responses.